# Interacting with iFrames Using Splinter/Selenium [Python]

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, iframe, splinter

note: a solution in either Selenium or API wrapper Splinter for Selenium is fine!

I have been having issues interacting with the iframes on Twitter.com using the Splinter API for Python.

For example,

```
with Browser('firefox', profile_preferences= proxySettings) as browser:
    #...login and do other stuff here
    browser.find_by_id('global-new-tweet-button').click()
```

this brings up a pop-up box to type in a tweet.

How do I interact with this new box using Splinter to:
1) fill in a message
2) click "tweet" (submit)
..programmatically of course.

I tried inspecting the element but it doesn't seem to be nested inside of an iframe however it targets an iframe. So I am not sure how to find/interact with the elements in this pop-up.

I tried manually typing in a message then clicking the tweet button programmatically:

```
browser.find_by_css('.btn.primary-btn.tweet-action.tweet-btn.js-tweet-btn').click()
```

..but I get the error:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///var/folders/z1/8rqrglqn2dj8_yj1z2fv5j700000gn/T/tmppRsJvd/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///var/folders/z1/8rqrglqn2dj8_yj1z2fv5j700000gn/T/tmppRsJvd/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/z1/8rqrglqn2dj8_yj1z2fv5j700000gn/T/tmppRsJvd/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/z1/8rqrglqn2dj8_yj1z2fv5j700000gn/T/tmppRsJvd/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/z1/8rqrglqn2dj8_yj1z2fv5j700000gn/T/tmppRsJvd/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

I strictly want to achieve my goal using Splinter so please do not offer alternatives, I know there are other ways.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You primary problem seems to be that you are treating the results of `browser.find_by_xxx` as an element object, when in reality it is an element container object (i.e. a list of webdriver elements).

Writing to the field works for me if I reference the element explicitly:

```
In [51]: elems = browser.find_by_id('tweet-box-global')
In [52]: len(elems)
Out[52]: 1
In [53]: elems[0].fill("Splinter Example")
In [54]:
```

That will write "Splinter Example" into the field for me.

The button click is failing because your css path is returning a list of three elements, and you are implicitly clicking on the first, hidden element. In my testing, the element you actually want to click on is the second element in the list:

```
In [26]: elems = browser.find_by_css('.btn.primary-btn.tweet-action.tweet-btn.js-tweet-btn')
In [27]: len(elems)
Out[27]: 3
In [28]: elems[1].click()
In [29]:
```

When I explicitly click the second element it doesn't throw an error and the button is clicked.

If you add to the css path you can narrow the results to only the button in the visible modal:

```
In [42]: css_path = "div.modal-tweet-form-container button.btn.primary-btn"
In [43]: elems = browser.find_by_css(css_path)
In [44]: len(elems)
Out[44]: 1
In [45]: elems.click()
In [46]:
```

Note that no exception was thrown here.